# How to show downloading progress Exoplayer

Tags: android, android-download-manager, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to download a video for offline in exoplayer, I want to show downloading progress inside an activity.

How can I bind to the `DownloadService` in exoplayer. so that I can update the current downloading progress in an activity? I try to override `onBind` method but there is no `onBind` method.

**DownloadService**

```kotlin
class MediaDownloadService : DownloadService(
    C.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, 1000,
    C.CHANNEL_ID, R.string.channel_name, R.string.channel_description
) {
    private lateinit var downloadManager: DownloadManager

    override fun onCreate() {
        downloadManager = DownloadUtil.getDownloadManager(this)
        downloadManager.addListener(object : DownloadManager.Listener {
            override fun onDownloadChanged(downloadManager: DownloadManager, download: Download) {
                if (download.bytesDownloaded == download.contentLength) {
                    toast("Download Completed!")
                }
                debug(download.failureReason)
            }
        })
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun getDownloadManager(): DownloadManager {
        return downloadManager
    }

    override fun getForegroundNotification(downloads: MutableList<Download>): Notification {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        val notificationHelper = DownloadNotificationHelper(this, C.CHANNEL_ID)

        return notificationHelper.buildProgressNotification(
            R.drawable.ic_notification,
            pendingIntent,
            "simple message",
            downloads
        )
    }

    override fun getScheduler(): Scheduler? {
        return null
    }

    inner class DownloadBinder: Binder() {
        val service: MediaDownloadService
            get() = this@MediaDownloadService
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To show the current download progress in an activity

1. You need to override and listen to the [`DownloadTracker.Listener`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/b2333c86c1eac9a1f95992960a8495f1e5b79200/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/DownloadTracker.java#L60) which will enable you to know the different state of your download.
2. When the state is at `Download.STATE_DOWNLOADING` start a coroutine/flow to send the current value of the download to your activity.
   I have used this flow (which send every 1 second the value of the percentDownload of the download you'd like)

```kotlin
val downloadManager: DownloadManager // is set before in my object
suspend fun getCurrentProgressDownload(uri: Uri?): Flow<Float?> {
    var percent: Float? = downloadManager.currentDownloads.find { it.request.uri == uri }?.percentDownloaded
    return callbackFlow {
        while(percent != null) {
            percent = downloadManager.currentDownloads.find { it.request.uri == uri }?.percentDownloaded
            offer(percent)
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Display it the way you like

I have created a repository where you can see download progress in the activity, This is merely an example that could use some optimisation.

https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin/tree/master/downloadvideo/src/main/java/io/github/yoobi/downloadvideo

if some thing are not clear don't hesitate to ask